# scheme using foldr to find the largest number in a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a list of grades,

```
(define grades 
    (list (make-grade 'D 62) (make-grade 'C 79) (make-grade 'A 93) (make-grade 'B 84) 
          (make-grade 'F 57) (make-grade 'F 38) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'A 95)
          (make-grade 'C 76) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'F 55) (make-grade 'C 74)
          (make-grade 'A 92) (make-grade 'B 86) (make-grade 'F 43) (make-grade 'C 73)))

;; A Grade is: (make-grade Symbol Number)
(define-struct grade (letter num))
```

I'm trying to find the biggest number in this list of grades structure by using foldr,

```
;; best-grade: Lof[Grade] -> Number 
;; find the highest Grade in list 

(define (best-grade log)
   (cond
      [(empty? log) 0]
      [(cons? log) (foldr max (grade-num (first log)) (grade-num (rest log)))]))
(check-expect (best-grade grades) 95)
```

Instead, it given **grade-num: expects a grade, given (list (make-grade 'C 79) (make-grade 'A 93) (make-grade 'B 84) (make-grade 'F 57) (make-grade 'F 38) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'A 95) (make-grade 'C 76) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'F 55) (make-grade 'C 74) (make-grade 'A 92) (make-grade '...**

I'm pretty sure (grade-num (first log)) inputs the number value of the grade. Anyone knows why??? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foldr` (or `foldl`, for that matter) successively calls a procedure you provide with 2 arguments:

- the elements of the list, one by one
- the previous result your procedure returned, or the initial value if it's the first call

*Note: In Racket, the order of the arguments is the opposite of standard Scheme*

so `foldr` already does the looping for you.

An example implementation would therefore be

```
(define (best-grade log)
  (foldr
   (lambda (grade best) ; procedure
     (let ((g (grade-num grade)))
       (if (or (not best) (> g best)) g best)))
   #f                   ; intitial value for best
   log))                ; list to process
```

then

```
> (best-grade grades)
95
> (best-grade '())
#f
```

In this case, usinf `foldl` would yield the same result and is therefore preferable, as @DWilches points out, because it is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct:

```
(grade-num (first log))
```

as  `(first log)` is an struct of type `grade`.

But this is not correct:

```
(grade-num (rest log))
```

because `(rest log)` is a list, not a struct of type `grade`.

EDIT: You seem to be confused about what parameters `foldr` expects. Take a look at the documentation of `foldl` (yes, `foldl`, not `foldr`). [(Here)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29)

Comment: I'm thinking to `map` the list first and then `foldr` the `map`ed list.

Answer (score 0):

```
;; best-grade: Lof[Grade] -> Number 
;; find the highest Grade in list 

(define (best-grade log)
    (cond
       [(empty? log) 0]
       [(cons? log) (foldr max 0 (log->lon log))]))

(check-expect (best-grade grades) 95)

;; log->lon: Lof[Grade] -> Lof[Number]
;; contains just the numerical grade

(define (log->lon log)
  (map grade-num log))
```